# Mouse Cursor Freezes Randomly with Intel GMA 950

Tags: 10.10, mouse, wubi, intel-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.  It's installed using Wubi, dual booting with Windows. It's a fresh install.

At random times, the mouse cursor freezes and I can't click anything on the screen. I can move the mouse but I can't click.

An example:
*Occurred when selecting text.*
So I use the keyboard to to reboot system. Then it is back to normal after reboot. I tried unplugging-plugging the mouse, but this didn't work.

PC: Asus laptop with Intel GMA 950 graphic card. A4 tech optical mouse. Ubuntu 10.10 completely updated and upgraded.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me sometimes too.

I just click something using the touchpad (not the mouse) at it returns to normal. I'd open a bug, but I can't replicate it, seems to be random. Likely it's related to some weird touchpad/mouse driver combination.